# Find all the words that contain the braces

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to find, within a string, all the words that contain the braces.
Here is an example of the string.

```
"Lorem ips{#A}um {1}dolor sit amet, definiebas{FD} cotidieque {11Y} sed et."
```

The words found should be:

```
"ips{#A}um"
"{1}dolor"
"definiebas{FD}"
"{11Y}"
```

I have arrived at this solution but it is partial

```
[\w-{']*(?:\}+[\w-']*)+
```

I can't catch the left side of the word.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/TiP1Y2/9) an example.

Comment: `\w*(?:\{#?\w+}\w*)+`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/74K3Dx/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/\w*(?:\{#?\w+}\w*)+/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/74K3Dx/1)

**Details**

- `\w*` - 0 or more word characters
- `(?:\{#?\w+}\w*)+` - one or more repetitions of

  - `\{` - a `{` char
  - `#?` - an optional `#` symbols
  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
  - `}` - a `}` char
  - `\w*` - 0 or more word chars

JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "Lorem ips{#A}um {1}dolor sit amet, definiebas{FD} cotidieque {11Y} sed et.";
const regex = /\w*(?:\{#?\w+}\w*)+/g;
console.log(text.match(regex));
```